# Saw <?var type="string" ?> in an XML string, but what does this mean?

Tags: xml

I recently saw an XML string containing `<?var type="string" ?>`. I would like to know if anyone has any idea what this means? It has something to do with PHP I imagine. Here is a contextual snippet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node>
   <?var type="string" ?>
   <somenode>Value</somenode>
</node>
```

I can't seem to search google for `<?var` so maybe you guys can help me out.

Comment: I would think in that context it would be an XML property, not a PHP property (variable).

Comment: Googling for `<?var` is about as useful as googling for `<node`. Both var and node presumably mean something to the sender and recipient of this particular document, but unless they have agreed to use an XML vocabulary that is described in a public standard, neither name means anything to anyone else.

Comment: For some context this snippet is found in the Zend PHP5.3 Certification study guide. (Data Types & Formats Chapter, Question 1) see: http://downloads.zend.com/guides/php5.3/PHP_5-3_Study_Guide_v1a.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an [XML processing instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi), and has nothing to do with PHP. (It isn't legal PHP syntax anyway.) The XML declaration you see at the beginning of the document is a special kind of PI.

I can't say much beyond that, though, as I've honestly never seen XML PIs used as XML PIs for anything in the wild, ever. <del>The `<? ?>` delimiters are usually recognized by developers as PHP delimiters (with a short opening delimiter) instead.</del>

Actually, as discussed in the comments, the full PHP delimiters `<?php ?>` can be considered a kind of processing instruction, even though they're used in a ton of other places besides XHTML/XML documents. One could even say that PHP was *designed* to be XHTML-compliant via processing instructions.

In fact, the following XHTML markup, with a snippet of PHP, actually [validates](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><?php echo 'Hello world!'; ?></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, it does not validate with short opening tags, as an XML PI must begin with `<?` followed by at least one name character. See the very first link to the spec for the PI grammar.

Comment: So it's possible to use PHP as XML processing instruction :)

Comment: @hakre: It depends on the syntax and context, really. I don't know how PIs are actually... processed, or what processes them (the PHP interpreter? Some other interpreter?).

Comment: PIs are processed by the application processing the XML. So for example, if you load an XML document into PHP then PHP would process these instructions.

Comment: @hakre: So I suppose PHP designed its delimiters for use with XHTML/XML! Clever. Unfortunately for us, they just killed XHTML :(

Comment: But aren't the shorthand `<?` highly discriminated against because of the intermixing problem that this question touches on? I would think something would have to handle the *XML* instructions, but (I've always understood) XML could be *parsed* on output by PHP if done right.

Comment: `<?` start of processing instruction, `php` defines the name and then the obigatory whitspace. That's: `<?php `. So it actually only works with non-short-tags. @BoltClock: Who killed XHTML?

Comment: As @hakre asks, what are you talking about vis a vis *they just killed XHTML*?

Comment: @hakre - So you're saying in XML parsing that `<?` will not be parsed if there is no identifier following it?

Comment: The HTML5 working group, who else :P Anyway I've updated my answer with something a little more interesting...

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Exactly, and as BoltClock already pointed out in the updated answer. HTML does not have these instructions, so they killed it :) I think that's what BoltClock meant. But there is as well XHTML 5.

Answer (score 5):

This is whats in the zend 5-5 study guide.
The question is "What is wrong with this XML document?" and the answer is "nothing"

### I suppose the  part is for php code but the repeated xml declaration seems weird so I put this xml in a file and opened it in my browser and the error:

This page contains error on line 7 at column 6: `XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document`. Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

### Value

So why does the study guide say there's nothing wrong with the xml??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node>
    <?var type="string" ?>
    <leaf>Value</leaf>
</node>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node>
    <?var type="string" ?>
    <leaf>Value</leaf>
</node>
```

Comment: Same here, I get this error when instantiating xml-1.xml with SimpleXMLElement with data as url set as true.   Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): xml-1.xml:6: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document